# pgbench-tools failed authentication

Tags: postgresql, authentication, benchmark, redhat

I'm trying to configure pgbench-tools and went to run it per the README and got this error

```
-bash-4.2$ ./newset 'Initial Config'
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I looked at my `pg_hba.conf` file and local is set to `trust`, so not sure where the error is coming, I made sure the pgbench-tools/config file is set for user postgres. Trying to figure out where this problem is coming from and haven't seen anywhere on pgbench-tools repository that shines any light.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that only the "local" record is set to trust.
try something like that:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

this should work for all kinds of local connections.